# Application data stored in Library/Caches being persisted across app installs

Tags: ios

I have some application state data that I am storing in the Library Caches folder, and have been noticing when I delete the app from my device, then build and run the app again, the same file exists.

Is this just a symptom of debug development or does this behaviour actually occur in production? Where else am I to store such files if I really want them to only exist per installation?

Comment: refer apple document - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: @Signare Thanks, but this doesn't mention anything about retention of the Caches folder?